# How to clear a ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

The following iterate over an  `ArrayList`:

```
for (String[] line : dataList) {
//adding items in the list here
    item.add(line[0]);

  if(dataList.isEmpty()){ //attempting to clear dataList when it has iterated through to the last element but not working as expected
    dataList.clear()
   }
}
```

How can I clear the elements in the `ArrayList` after I have iterater over its elements?

Comment: `if(dataList.isEmpty())` it will always return `false`.So your `dataList.clear()` will never be called.

Comment: wait !! If it's empty, why are you clearing it ? :p doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: change `If(dataList.isEmpty())` to `if(!dataList.isEmpty())`

Comment: Just call `dataList.clear()` **after the loop**. Don't even bother to check if it is empty.

Comment: Could you imagine, I can't find a dupe for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `if(dataList.isEmpty())` block and clear the list after the loop.  Iterating does not remove items.

The desired code is:

```
for (String[] line : dataList) {
    item.add(line[0]);
}
dataList.clear();
```

Comment: Edited and added code. Now the answer is much higher quality. Please read [answer] - it helps in writing answers that are better received.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like,

```
for (String[] line : dataList) {
    item.add(line[0]);
}

dataList.clear();
```

Comment: Why would you check if `dataList` is empty?

Comment: I know what it was, but it was redundant

Answer (score 0):

As others point out:

```
for (String[] line : dataList) {
    item.add(line[0]);
}
dataList.clear();
```

Will clear the list. If it's already empty, that's fine. `clear()` will do nothing and return normally.

I've popped an answer in because you might wonder if you need to clear it at all. If `dataList` goes out of scope at the end of the method then the garbage collector will clear up for you.

If you're 'reusing' `datalist` in subsequent code then the best answer is - don't. Declare a local variable at the start of the loop. It's certainly cleaner and often faster to just keep creating new objects rather than recycling.

NB: There could be circumstances where clearing the list is appropriate. If it's a class field that will continue beyond the method. However if it is the use as a temporary store seems inappropriate.